# I am unable to access my inbuilt webcam. Everytime I turn it on it shows no device detected

Tags: drivers, webcam, camera, ubuntu-drivers, cheese

Initially I had windows 10 there also the camera was not being detected.But here also same thing is happening

```
$ cheese
Message: 12:39:34.374: cheese-application.vala:214: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:2709): cheese-CRITICAL **: 12:39:34.386: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:2709): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:39:34.386: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:2709): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:39:34.386: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:2709): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:39:34.386: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:2709): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:39:34.386: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:2709): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 12:39:34.386: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:2709): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:39:34.386: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:2709): CRITICAL **: 12:39:34.386: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

Comment: If the camera is not detected by Windows or Ubuntu, then you probably have a broken camera ... 

Comment: @Matigo I think that might be the case because I tried everything I could and finally thought if I might have missed something I could get help here. But I guess there might be a hardware problem.